# How do I re-install python on the mac, but version 3.2 (latest) and have all the command line stuff work

Tags: python, macos

I uninstalled python using the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

sudo rm -rf /Applications/Python *
```

then deleted all python related things in here:

```
 /usr/local/bin
```

And I just installed python 3.2, but the terminal python doesn't work, `$> python` doesn't do anything, other than say command not found

I uninstalled all the python stuff, because, there was a problem with the older pythons using global site-packages... so I figured it would be good to start clean (i had like... 5 versions before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Try ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads)**. Not only does it automatically create symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`, but also comes with a tool called [`pythonselect`](https://github.com/ActiveState/pythonselect#readme) which you can use to set the "active" Python version.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm not sure I'd really go around deleting things that were installed my Mac OS.... grab your install CD and get the default Python back :)

Then install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) type `sudo port install python32` and you'll have a seperate install of Python 3.2 in /opt somewhere safe from the default one.

Comment: Although I like the concept of MacPorts, I wasn't too happy that it is a complete ecosystem and tends to pull in all sorts of stuff that already exists.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the nature of package managers is that they need to know where everything came from. I feel a little hypocritical as in my current setup I've installed everything from source for that very reason. but I still recommend macports for ease of use.

Comment: Except when maybe some dependencies are out of whack because of out-of-sync versions. I much prefer an auto-managed ecosystem.

Comment: +1 for the remark about not messing up with OS X, and for suggesting a package manager.  I would go with Fink instead of MacPorts, though, because it contains many more packages.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to figure out is where your current installation is. The reason I ask is because I have several versions of python installed side-by-side though each with a different name. /usr/local/bin/python is just a sym-link to the real binary file.

For example, maybe you have /usr/local/bin/python-3.2 instead of /usr/local/bin/python. Once you know where it is, all you have to do is create a symbolic link to it via:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python-3.2 /usr/local/bin/python
```

That's only an example of course and you're paths might be different. Also you'll have to run that command as root (sudo).